# Percentile_Disc on SQL Server Group By error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, percentile

Please help I get an Error message when I try to use Group By on a selected column when I use PERCENTILE_DISC to not get duplicate results. This is the syntax I used .

```
SELECT Grade,
  PERCENTILE_DISC(0.1) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Salary) OVER(PARTITION BY Grade) AS '10th_Percentile',
  PERCENTILE_DISC(0.25) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Salary) OVER(PARTITION BY Grade) AS '25th_Percentile',
  PERCENTILE_DISC(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Salary) OVER(PARTITION BY Grade) AS '50th_Percentile',
  PERCENTILE_DISC(0.75) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Salary) OVER(PARTITION BY Grade) AS '75th_Percentile',
  PERCENTILE_DISC(0.9) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Salary) OVER(PARTITION BY Grade) AS '90th_Percentile'
FROM Employees_Rank
GROUP BY Grade;
```

I even tried using Approximate PERCENTILE_DISC  and I still get the same error message:

> "Column is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in
> either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

I also tried using DISTINCT Function but that only calculates one unique value.

Comment: Hard to visualize your desired results, but you can't mix the window functions with a GROUP BY.  Try removing the GROUP BY

Comment: yeah a bit cumbersome but the method in the dupe works for you https://dbfiddle.uk/i3MgZBWE